# MAAS 1.9.1 PXE boot looking for Xenial image but i have trusty

Tags: juju, maas

MAAS 1.9.1 .....I deployed couple of nodes in MAAS and deployment went fine with 14.04 trusty image.....On my third node commissioning at PXE boot it start to look for Xenial image and failing with error: file not found ..... because Xenial is not in MAAS server....The only image i downloaded is 14.04 trusty......How can i make sure that MAAS server stick to 14.04 trusty image only for all my node deployment.....

regiond.log:2016-04-22 17:46:38 [maasserver] ERROR: Unable to identify boot image for (ubuntu/amd64/generic/xenial/commissioning): cluster 'maas' does not have matching boot image.

Comment: what is the default series mentioned in your environments.yaml file?

Comment: there is no environment.yaml file

Comment: Never mind, i got it wrong. Have you looked at the logs in /var/log/maas/, it might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the maas ui..go the settings>deploy options and change the Default Ubuntu release used for commissioning.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your operating system used for deployment has somehow changed to Ubuntu 16.04. Take a look at MAAS > Settings > Deploy or run

```
sudo -u postgres psql -d maasdb -c "select * from maasserver_config"
```

from command line and look for xenial right to default_distro_series setting (just don't post here the output of sensitive settings).

Comment: Actually somehow it changed to Xenial under settings --> deploy and commissioning ...... Changed it back to Trusty and everything went back to normal.....

Comment: @aavam: If this answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.